# How to use SSE4.1 instructions without install tensorflow from source?

Tags: tensorflow

I have tried to install Tensorflow from source according to guide on its official site, but the experience is very unpleasant.

The immediate outcome of unable to install from source I can see is the following:

```
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

I wonder whether there is a way to 'use SSE4.1 instructions' and other instructions mentioned above without installing Tensorflow from source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to use SIMD instructions without building TensorFlow from source.

TensorFlow binaries come by default without this optimization to increase compatibility with the wider range of CPU architectures as possible.

If you want to silence the warnings though you can set `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` to 2 as:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
```

This TF environment variable defaults to `0`, showing all logs. 
Setting it to `1` will filter out `INFO` logs and `2` will additionally silence `WARNING` logs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wonder whether TF is going to simplify the process of installing from source in the future. do you know anything about this? thanks

Comment: Installing from source is not trivial but if you follow the docs you'll be able to do it without problems. There are always improvements being made and feedback is always welcome. If you have any suggestions on how the Docs could be improved for instance feel free to open an issue on Github :)
  In which OS you tried to build? Usually Windows is the more experimental to build with CPU optimizations but even on it is working successfully.

Comment: BTW, there is a non official Github repo of [TensorFlow community wheels](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels) where users share their builds. Visit issues to see the available builds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your encourange! I use Mac, and I went through the whole installing process suggested on the doc. But there were so many warning messages I even don't know where to begin. Do you really think it is worthy the effort to get tensorflow installed from the source? If so, I will find time to do it

Comment: No problem :) I can't really say for you, I don't know what your priorities or goals are but personally I think is worth it. There were users that achieved 3x improved speed for large matrix multiply on Xeon-V3 with FMA/AVX for instance. I'd suggest you post the issues you're facing when building from source here or on TensorFlow Github repo under issues. If you have time constraints just go with the official builds

Comment: I tried to install tensorflow from source again, but can't find `whl` file, could you have a look at it for me? thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364264/how-to-find-whl-file-when-installing-tensorflow-from-source-for-mac