# How to install tensorflow from source for Mac

Tags: installation, tensorflow

I have followed the steps [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) to install tensorflow from sources on Mac.

The latest problem on no effect is in the updated section at the bottom of this page.

The most immediate problem (solved now) I have was I can't find `whl` file to do `sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-py2-none-any.whl`

Before it, although I didn't get error, I have got tons of warnings when running `bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`. The following is only the last part of the logging message with warnings.

```
arning: class 'WorkerEnv' was previously declared as a struct [-Wmismatched-tags]
class WorkerEnv;
^
./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker_env.h:37:8: note: previous use is here
struct WorkerEnv {
       ^
./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.h:28:1: note: did you mean struct here?
class WorkerEnv;
^~~~~
struct
In file included from tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:16:
./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.h:36:8: warning: 'tensorflow::GrpcWorker::RecvTensorAsync' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
  void RecvTensorAsync(CallOptions* opts, const RecvTensorRequest* request,
       ^
./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.h:72:8: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'tensorflow::Worker::RecvTensorAsync' declared here: type mismatch at 3rd parameter ('tensorflow::TensorResponse *' vs '::grpc::ByteBuffer *')
  void RecvTensorAsync(CallOptions* opts, const RecvTensorRequest* request,
       ^
2 warnings generated.
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/core/kernels/libconv_ops.pic.lo:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/conv_ops/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops_using_gemm.pic.o has no symbols
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/core/kernels/libfft_ops.pic.lo:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/fft_ops/tensorflow/core/kernels/fft_ops.pic.o has no symbols
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: warning for library: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/libfft_ops.pic.lo the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/core/libsycl_runtime.pic.lo:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/_objs/sycl_runtime/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/sycl/sycl_allocator.pic.o has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/_objs/sycl_runtime/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/sycl/sycl_device.pic.o has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/_objs/sycl_runtime/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/sycl/sycl_device_context.pic.o has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/_objs/sycl_runtime/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/sycl/sycl_device_factory.pic.o has no symbols
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: warning for library: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/libsycl_runtime.pic.lo the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/core/libgpu_runtime.pic.lo:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/_objs/gpu_runtime/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.pic.o has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/_objs/gpu_runtime/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device_factory.pic.o has no symbols
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_math_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/factorization/gen_gen_clustering_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_sparse_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_user_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/nccl/gen_nccl_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_nn_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_linalg_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_parsing_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/factorization/gen_gen_factorization_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/ffmpeg/gen_decode_audio_op_py_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_random_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/gen_gen_tensor_forest_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_io_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_resource_variable_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_functional_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_logging_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_script_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_set_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_cloud_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/layers/gen_bucketization_op_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_test_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_state_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_ctc_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_data_flow_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_sdca_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/input_pipeline/gen_input_pipeline_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/image/gen_image_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_string_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/layers/gen_sparse_feature_cross_op_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_candidate_sampling_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_image_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/ffmpeg/gen_encode_audio_op_py_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_training_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_array_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/python/gen_control_flow_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/contrib/framework/gen_gen_variable_ops_py_wrappers_cc [for host]:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package
INFO: Elapsed time: 2177.306s, Critical Path: 2134.22s
```

Then I ran `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`, it seems make no error with the following output in the console:

```
(dlnd-tf-lab)  ->bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
Wed Apr 12 16:09:42 CST 2017 : === Using tmpdir: /var/folders/gz/ch3n2mp51m9386sytqf97s6w0000gn/T/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX.WnIjTd5J
~/Downloads/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles ~/Downloads/tensorflow
~/Downloads/tensorflow
/var/folders/gz/ch3n2mp51m9386sytqf97s6w0000gn/T/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX.WnIjTd5J ~/Downloads/tensorflow
Wed Apr 12 16:09:45 CST 2017 : === Building wheel
~/Downloads/tensorflow
Wed Apr 12 16:10:02 CST 2017 : === Output wheel file is in: /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

Then I could not find the `whl` file, do you know where can I find it?

Thanks!

---

Now, I found the `whl` file, but there was no change to tensorflow after running the following code, also I got a warning. will this warning cause the problem for not making any effect on tensorflow?

```
(dlnd-tf-lab)  ->sudo pip install tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Password:
The directory '/Users/Natsume/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/Natsume/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow==1.0.1 from file:///Users/Natsume/Downloads/tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl in /Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in /Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.1.0 in /Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==1.0.1)
```

However, when I tried the code provided in the link above to check whether everything is working as expected, I still got the following warnings indicating there is no effect. Could anyone help me here? Thanks

```
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

Comment: Is there no file inside `/tmp/tensorflow_pkg`?

Comment: I can't find `/tmp/tensorflow_pkg` in the folders where tensorflow locates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To summarize my solution**

1. follow the official guide of installing tensorflow from source with the link provided in the question;
2. Be patient with installing `brew` and `bazel`:  to install bazel, go to [bazel](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/install.html). Make sure you have them up to the latest version. It was very slow to install or upgrade, but it will get you there, patience.
3. follow the official instruction all the way to the step of `./configure`, just use `default` options or `no` to set everything;
4. Now the last second step: official instruction tells you to `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`. However, in my case, I can find `/tmp/tensorflow_pkg` in my Mac. Fortunately, it will be seen if you run `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package Your_Full_Path/tmp/tensorflow_pkg`. Note, `tmp` folder and `tensorflow` folder are in the same directory or same level.
5. go to the directory where `tmp` and `tensorflow` are stored, run `pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.2.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl`
6. Now you did it.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel stated in the comments, utilizing the full path after TensorFlow successfully builds worked to access and install the wheel file.

Comment: but there is no such folder `tmp` inside my home directory either. Where else can it be?

Comment: when I ran `sudo pip` I will get this warning message `The directory '/Users/Natsume/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory.` I have no idea why my Mac always complain this. will this affect where the file is located?

Comment: I got it! I ran this code by giving a full path and it works and I can find it now: `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /Users/Natsume/Downloads/tmp/tensorflow_pkg`

Comment: Great you figured it out, will edit the answer to advise use full path. Still strange you were not able to do it as previously. Will look into it.

Comment: Thanks, could you have a look at my updated question above? I ran `sudo pip install tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl`, but there was no effect.

Comment: Just now, I eventually did it with this last step: 1. `cd Downloads/ `, 2. run `pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.2.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl` ; and done!